# Empty PO file when exporting WPML String Translation

Tags: string, translation, po, wpml

I have a question about the .po/.pot files I export from WPML String Translation plugin. I'm running some localisation tests in WordPress, and I have various strings that need to be translated. I want to have these translated in external translation software, so I need to make a .po/.pot file export.

However, when I use WPML String Translation to create an export of a context of strings, the resulting .pot file is empty apart from some header info. Not just lacking translation (that would make sense if it were a .pot file), but lacking any strings to be translated at all. This is what it looks like:

```css
# This file was generated by WPML
# WPML is a WordPress plugin that can turn any WordPress or WordPressMU site into a full featured multilingual content management system.
# https://wpml.org
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Project-Id-Version:WPML_EXPORT_admin_texts_wpseo_internallinks\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language:nl\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
```

Not visible here, but after the MIME-version line, instead of generating the combinations of msgid and msgstr you'd expect, it generates a blank line for each string that should be there (in this case there's 6 as the particular context contains 6 strings). This happens both in .po files and .pot files exported from WPML String Translation. Of course, without source strings the file is useless for an external translator.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this, and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling debug in Wordpress. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Debug_in_WordPress

Maybe is something memory related.
Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Hosting: http://tutorials.hostucan.net/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit/